# Why do Azure Functions not support System.Text.Json and everyone uses NewtonSoft in examples?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

Why do Azure Functions not support `System.Text.Json` and everyone uses newtonsoft in examples?

Is it possible to use System.Text.Json in Azure functions?

```cs
public static class FanyFunctionName
{
    [FunctionName("FanyFunctionName")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            // Read the request body and deserialize it
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var eventObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event>(requestBody);

            // Log the event type and other necessary information in one log statement
            return new OkResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex, "Error processing event");
            return new BadRequestObjectResult("Error processing event");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not like `system.json.Text` doesn't support but Azure function uses `Newtonsoft.Json` by default.

Comment: What Version? And Isolated-Process or In-Process? ...

Comment: We need to use `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` with `System.Text.Json` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` with `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the Comments, it is not like  `system.json.Text`  doesn't support but Azure function uses  `Newtonsoft.Json`  by default.

When we create Function App, by default, `requestBody` generates code with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` from  `Newtonsoft.Json`.

***Code with `Newtonsoft.Json`:***

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;
```

When we use `System.Text.Json` , `JsonConvert` is not allowed in the Function,

[image]

I tried with `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>` and got the below error.

[image]

I have modified the code as below, Now Iam able to access the Function.

***Using `System.Text.Json` :***

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
{
    dynamic data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data.GetProperty("name").GetString();
}
```

***Output:***
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `System.Text.Json` can be used in Azure Functions and WebJobs without any problems.